# Use img file as block device

Tags: filesystem, dd, disk-image

I created an `img` file using dd (`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/danialbehzadi/dong.img bs=1000K count=32`) and now I want it to be used as a block device, so I can restore a filesystem saved by `fasrachiver` into it.

I already tried restoring directly to file:

```
oper_restore.c#152,convert_argv_to_strdicos(): "dong.img" is not a valid block device
```

and mounting it and restoring there:

```
oper_restore.c#152,convert_argv_to_strdicos(): "/mnt" is not a valid block device
```

Is there a way to make it apperad in /dev directrory as a storage device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to configure loopback device by [`losetup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/losetup.8.html) as follows:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 ~/dong.img
```

and then you'll be able to see this image file as a raw disk at `/dev/loop0`:

> ```
> $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0 
> Disk /dev/loop0: 31.26 MiB, 32768000 bytes, 64000 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> ```

To detach device use `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0`.